# convert scientific notation to decimal with php

Tags: php

math with bitcoin is giving me problems

```
        $value = bcmul((float)$TotalMoney, $p,8);
        $value = bcdiv((float)$Value, 100,8);
```

returns 8.431e-05 as one of the values in the script

i've tried

```
$newNum = (float)$value; 
$newNum = number_format((float)$value, 8); 
$newNum = sprintf('%.8f',$value);

function scientific_notation($in_float_value, $in_decimal_place_count = -1) 
{

  // Get the exponent
  $abs_float_value = abs($in_float_value);
  $exponent = floor($abs_float_value == 0 ? 0 : log10($abs_float_value));
  // Scale to get the mantissa
  $in_float_value *= pow(10, -$exponent);
  // Create the format string based 
  // on the requested number of decimal places.
  $format = ($in_decimal_place_count >= 0) ? "." . $in_decimal_place_count : "";
  //echo("Format0: $format");
  // Format the exponent part using zero padding.
  $formatted_exponent = "+" . sprintf("%02d", $exponent);
  if($exponent < 0.0)
  {
      $formatted_exponent = "-" . sprintf("%02d", -$exponent);
  }
  $format = "%" . $format . "fe%s";
  //echo("Format1: $format");
  // Return the final value combining mantissa and exponent
  return sprintf($format, $in_float_value, $exponent);

}
$newNum = scientific_notation($value,8);
```

Tried it in phpfiddle and it works. maybe the problem is storing it in a db. It's stores as 8.431e-05 in the database

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sprintf('%.8f',floatval($value));` worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

**Use the exemple below to convert Scientific Notation to float/decimal on PHP:**

```
echo sprintf('%f', floatval('-1.0E-5'));//default 6 decimal places
echo sprintf('%.8f', floatval('-1.0E-5'));//force 8 decimal places
echo rtrim(sprintf('%f',floatval(-1.0E-5)),'0');//remove trailing zeros
```

Answer (score 4):

When working with Bitcoin balances it is recommended to store amounts in a database in satoshis as an integer and then you can convert it back to 8 decimals when displaying it on the screen to users.

```
$amount = 0.0132;
$convert = $amount * 100000000;
// store in DB as the converted amount 1320000 as an integer
// when grabbing from DB convert it back
$databaseValue = 1320000;
$convertBack = $databaseValue / 100000000;
$display = number_format($convertBack, 8); 
echo $display;
```